# Read strings from file, than save them to a matrix

Tags: c, file

I've been trying to read random characters from a non formatted .txt file like this one:

```
sadfhjk
xcvbnm
dfghjkl
```

and then to have them saved to a matrix to be then printed out on another file, but i keep getting results like this one and I can't understand why i get those random strings after my input:

```
sadfhjk
xþcvbnm
dfgwhjkl
//random strings starting from there
iEwcvbnm
dfgwhjkl
iEwhjkl
iEwdääŠ€@@Àþ))þÿÿÿJsDw=tDwà@Dwà@
```

This is the code I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 5
#define DIM 10

int main()
{
    int i=0, c=0, j=0;
    char matrice[DIM][DIM];

    FILE *ifp, *ofp;

    ifp=fopen("C:\\Users\\messa\\OneDrive\\PoliTo\\Anno II\\Algoritmi\\Laboratori\\lab2\\es2\\input.txt", "r");
    if (ifp==NULL) printf("Impossibile aprire file!\n");

    ofp=fopen("C:\\Users\\messa\\OneDrive\\PoliTo\\Anno II\\Algoritmi\\Laboratori\\lab2\\es2\\output.txt", "w");
    if (ofp==NULL) printf("Impossibile aprire file!\n");

    for(i=0; i<DIM-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<DIM-1;j++){
            fscanf(ifp,"%c", &matrice[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<DIM; i++) fprintf(ofp, "%s", matrice[i]);

    fclose(ofp);
    fclose(ifp);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(i=0; i<DIM-1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<DIM-1;j++){
            fscanf(ifp,"%c", &matrice[i][j]);
        }
    }` --> `while(i < DIM && fscanf(ifp,"%9s", matrice[i]) == 1)
   i++;` and `for(i=0; i<DIM; i++) fprintf(ofp, "%s", matrice[i]);` --> `for(j = 0;  j < i; j++) fprintf(ofp, "%s\n", matrice[j]);`

Comment: Your program continues execution, trying to access the input and/or output files even when the file fails to open.   Suggest, when a file fails to open, output the error message (best to use something like `perror()` as then the output is to stderr and includes the system message as to why the error occurred..  Then, cleanup, for instance by closing any open file, then exit the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code:

- cleanly compiles
- properly reads in the input file, one line per row of matrice
- stops outputting when at end of used matrice rows
- contains comments on what is being done
- removes unneeded `#define`s and `int` variables
- documents what the variables are being used for
- will properly stop reading input file when at end of file
- reads full rows from input file, including the newlines
- so printing the rows requires no 'tweaking' or extra `printf()` formatting

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// wrap #define values in parens to avoid 'text substitution' errors
// only #define items actually used in the code
// make the matrice plenty big so acquire full input line
#define DIM (50)

int main()
{
    // only declare one variable per statement, for readability, understandability and ease of documentation
    int i; // tracks which row of matrix on input, total rows on output
    int j; // tracks which row of matrix on output
    char matrice[DIM][DIM] = {{'\0'}};  // pre initialize so easy to print as strings

    FILE *ifp = NULL;
    FILE *ofp = NULL;

    ifp=fopen("C:\\Users\\messa\\OneDrive\\PoliTo\\Anno II\\Algoritmi\\Laboratori\\lab2\\es2\\input.txt", "r");
    if (ifp==NULL)
    { // fopen failed, report it, (nothing to cleanup), exit
        perror("fopen for input.txt file failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    ofp=fopen("C:\\Users\\messa\\OneDrive\\PoliTo\\Anno II\\Algoritmi\\Laboratori\\lab2\\es2\\output.txt", "w");
    if (ofp==NULL)
    { // then fopen failed, report it, cleanup, exit
        perror("fopen for output.txt file failed");
        fclose( ifp ); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else fopen successful

    // following loop stops when at end of input file or matrix is full
    // Note: input file is formatted in lines, so read it line by line
    // NOte: fgets() reads in full line from input file, including the 'newline'
    //       so no need to append newline when printing matrix later
    for( i=0; (i < DIM) && fgets( &matrice[i][0], DIM, ifp ); i++);

    // Note: 'i' now contains number of used rows in matrice

    // print contents of matrix
    for(j=0; j<i; j++) fprintf(ofp, "%s", matrice[j]);

    // cleanup
    fclose(ofp);
    fclose(ifp);


    return 0;
} // end function: main
```

Comment: Your code is so beautiful I'm crying! Thank you for your instructive comments!

Answer (score 1):

- You have to put null character `'\0'` at the end of string if you use `%s`.
- `matrice[DIM-1]` is not initialized and its contents is indeterminate.

Change `char matrice[DIM][DIM];` to `char matrice[DIM][DIM]={{0}};` so that it is initialized and have `'\0'` after each string and the last line will be an empty string.

Comment: It is amazing how many people don't snap to the fact that if they will just initialize their arrays to zero, they get automatic `null-termination` of strings for free.

Comment: The funny thing is that I always initialize each and every variable but I didn't thought of arrays!

Answer (score 0):

`"%s"` prints a null-terminated string, but your matrix isn't null-terminated. Use two nested loops for output and the `"%c"` format. Alternatively, use the unused last element of each row to place a null character `'\0'`.